# Can somebody tell me about this slash in path?

Tags: html, django

Can somebody tell me the difference between two paths?

This is my urls.py in django

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('update/<int:id>/', views.update),
]
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('update/<int:id>', views.update),
]
```

```
<form action="/app/update/{id}/" method="POST">
```

Why I should add slash(/) in the end of path?

If I add / in path in urlpatterns, when I submit , it works well.

If I don't, it occurs an error.

Comment: guess it depends on the server? looks odd that you'd end the path with a `/` though - but, your server code would explain it

Comment: With apache/PHP and without an .htaccess file the first URL will go to `/app/update/index.php` while the second will look for a file called `update` inside the `app` folder.

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry I don't explain my question in detail...
I edit my question again.

Comment: @ChrisG Is it means when the path is 'update/foo ',
It will look for a file called foo in update folder..?

Comment: As long as the URL matches a pattern it should work without the slash. You have posted two `urlpatterns` up there, which one are you using? Also, what error message do you get?

Comment: Yes. The added info and django tag go a long way to explain your issue

Answer (score 1):

"/" Is just Required in Django probbably from safety reasons like query string colide with path etc..

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urls/